# What is "immediate mode" in LWJGL?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am not sure what "immediate mode" is in the context of LWJGL. I think it's when you use `gluPerspective()` function?

Answer (score 2):

It refers to using OpenGL's direct (immediate) mode of rendering (the family of functions that includes `glBegin` and `glEnd` as well as all the immediate vertex attribute specification functions like `glVertex*` and `glColor*`).

Immediate mode functionality is deprecated in modern OpenGL/ If available, something like [vertex buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object#Vertex_Buffer_Object) should be used instead.

`gluPerspective` is not an immediate-mode function, but it is a utility function that makes use of OpenGL's matrix stack, which is also deprecated.

Comment: Just want to add that it's perfectly acceptable to use "immediate mode" when rapid prototyping, and in early development (when things change all the time), to get things on the screen quickly.